# SOAP Body elements

Tags: java, apache-axis

After generating client code from WSDL everything is proper. But after envelope I did a sysout and the body elements has

```
<http: / www.siebel.com /xml / ContactInfo>xyz</http://www.siebel.com/xml/ContactInfo>
<http: /www.siebel.com /xml / ContactInfo>John</http://www.siebel.com/xml/ContactInfo>
<http:/www.siebel.com /xml / ContactInfo>Smith</http://www.siebel.com/xml/ContactInfo>
```

instead of some thing like this

```
<sov:Contact>
               <sov:PersonUId>xyz</sov:PersonUId>

               <sov:FirstName>John</sov:FirstName>
               <sov:LastName>Smith</sov:LastName>
</sov:contact>
```

Should I add any code to look like `<sov:contact>` instead of `<http: / www.siebel.com /xm....`

Comment: It looks like there is some bad configuration in your server? I dont know. Please can you provide some more information?

Comment: what information do you need... its properly working from SOAP UI. Basically I generated client code from wsdl and then while debugging line by line and printing out envelope I see strange http:// stuff instead of elements... Let me know if you need any thing else...

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by [AXIOM-421](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIOM-421). The issue occurs with certain Axiom versions in combination with certain StAX implementations.

The solution is either to upgrade to a newer Axiom version or to add Woodstox to your application so that it is used instead of Weblogic's StAX implementation.